# Multi-Column b-tree index logic?

Tags: database, b-tree, database-indexes, raptordb

I know how to implement a b-tree for single-column indexes, but how do I implement a b-tree for multi-column indexes in my rdbms project?

For example, I have a table consisting of documents records:

```
Documents
-------------
id
serial_no
order_no
record_sequence
```

If I make an index with 3 columns, for example:

```
CREATE INDEX UNIQUE myindex(serial_no, order_no, record_sequence);
```

then I have a key name for my b-tree structure in this format:
`serial_no*order_no*record_sequence`.

I can request a record via this index and this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE serial_no='ABC' AND order_no=500 AND record_sequence=0;
```

Note: I am creating an index record `ABC*500*0` as b-tree key name.

But when I call all records of a document, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE serial_no='ABC' AND order_no=500;
```

I cannot use my index to search for records because record_sequence is missing in this example.

As a result, what is the method of creating and searching multi-column indexes?

As far as I know my b-tree object does not support searching for "ABC*500*ANY". I am using a [RaptorDB_v2.7.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375413/RaptorDB-the-Document-Store) b-tree object:

> RaptorDB - the Document Store
>
> NoSql, JSON based, Document store database with compiled .net map functions and automatic hybrid bitmap indexing and LINQ query filters

Comment: why do you say that you cannot use the index on 2nd query ?

Comment: for the example you posted, that index should be used - does it happen differently ?

Comment: I mean "SELECT * FROM Documents serial_no='ABC' AND order_no=500;" query, how can I search in btree structure without record_secuence column? Thanks.

Comment: order_no is first column of the index, it can use the index with a seek, also, you provide a value for 2nd column of the index => it will return all values from there on, because it doesn't need to filter on that 3rd column of the index.

Comment: But I am creating btree record as "ABC*500*0" for this record, How can I search btree keys records without 3rd parameter. For example ABC 500 document consist of  3 records and these btree keys : "ABC*500*0", "ABC*500*1", "ABC*500*2"

Comment: you are searching for "ABC*500*ANY" which will return "ABC*500*0", "ABC*500*1", "ABC*500*2"

Comment: As I know my btree object does not support searching as "ABC*500*ANY", I am using RaptorDB_v2.7.5 btree object.

Comment: Are you *"implementing" a b-tree index or *delcaring and using* one? Please be clearer about what you want to do. And why did you tag with rdbms & rdms when RaptorDB is apparently not a rdbms but is a linq-queried nosql db?

Comment: "As I know my btree object does not support" is unclear. Also, have you read [The Key Value Store V2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/316816/RaptorDB-The-Key-Value-Store-V2)?

Comment: Maybe you can suggest a disk-based btree object that support wildcards. Thanks.